# Preserve all items after selecting with multiselect widget

Tags: streamlit

I want to preserve all items after selecting from multiselect widget. For example, with this code:

```
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
st.multiselect('test: ', tuple(values), key='1')
```

after I select ‘a’, the option left to select is ‘b’ and ‘c’. Is it possible to preserve all items (‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’), after selecting one?

Comment: Not possible. You can use selectbox instead.

Comment: Is there an update on this issue? Seems like a usual use-case to me